# vim color is different between local and remote machine's screen

Tags: vim, colors, terminal, color-scheme

I have two machine which share the completely same `.vimrc` and `colorscheme`. I'm working on machine `Local`. When I open `vim` in `Local`'s terminal, it looks like:

[image]

The background is dark and color is contrasting.

Then I log in machine `Remote` through `ssh` on `Local`, and open `Remote`'s `vim` in `screen`. And then I see:

[image]

The background is grey and it looks different from `Local`'s `vim`. What happened?

**EDIT**: When I don't use `screen` everything works well. The ugly color only exists in `screen`.

Comment: It looks like a terminal setting issue.

Comment: Are you using tmux by any chance?

Comment: What terminal(s) are the two machines using? what does `echo $TERM` show at the shell prompt?

Comment: @wilhelmtell thank for your reminder. I'm using `screen` and when I leave it, my `vim` color looks okay. Now the problem is, I need `screen`, how to make `vim` color work in it?

Comment: Would [this](http://robotsrule.us/vim/) resolve your problem?

Comment: That's cool, I've written an answer so that you can mark the question as "answered" for children of the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](http://robotsrule.us/vim/), the problem is solved by adding these lines to `~/.screenrc`:

```
attrcolor b ".I"
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
defbce "on"
```